# Where can I find the historical source code of the Linux sources

Tags: linux, resources, statistics

I want to do research on the evolution of Linux.

Therefore it would be nice if I could download the sources of Linux at several moments in time (from 1991 till now).

Is there a site where one can find those sources?

Similar sites for other Unix based operating systems are also welcome.

Comment: Linux (the kernel), or GNU/Linux (the usable operating system)? The answers so far seem to talk mostly about the kernel.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest these two:

http://www.oldlinux.org/

and a more straightforward one from this site that contain Linux kernel 0.01, 0.10, 0.11,...,0.98:

http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/

and the other:

http://www.codeforge.com/article/170371

Answer (score 8):

Check this URL: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/

Answer (score 8):

[Archive.org](http://archive.org) hosts a [Git repo with the complete history of Linux](http://archive.org/details/git-history-of-linux), made by grafting 3 repositories together.  You'd probably need to do a `git pull` to update it with the most recent changes.

Answer (score 5):

[The Unix Heritage Society](http://www.tuhs.org/wiki/The_Unix_Heritage_Society) has a load of old Genuine Unix source code. The [source code page](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl) has Bell Labs Unix from Version 1 through 6, 32V, System III, some or all of the BSDs, pointers to Linux progenitor Minix.